# After using rsync, server no longer recognizes dynamic .css generation

Tags: php, wordpress, rsync

So, I have a Wordpress site, and I set up a `/dev` subdomain with a seperate Wordpress install to work on my theme. Everything was going great until I thought it would be clever to `ssh` into my server and use `rsync` to push updates from dev to the production directory.

Well, I'm pretty sure `rsync` broke something. A part of the site (that relies on a third-party theme) breaks when I try to add photos to posts, and I've determined that the Prod site, ever since I used `rsync`, will no longer cooperate with a `GET` request to dynamically generate `.css`.

**On the working Dev site, `post-new.php`:**

Everything works fine, although Chrome does tell me:

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://my.site.com/dev/wp-content/themes/my-theme/admin/css/post-formats.css/?ver=3.6`

Note that post-formats.css is dynamically generated through php.

**On the broken Prod site, `post-new.php`:**

Images will not successfully attach to posts, and Chrome tells me:

`GET http://jalph.net/wp-content/themes/my-theme/admin/css/post-formats.css?ver=3.6 404 (Not Found)`

Again, this is all on the same server, just in different directories. All of the `php` files are identical at this point, so it's not a matter of broken code.

I've checked file permissions, and they all seem to be the same.

**What in the world did `rsync` do to me?**

I know it must be a server thing... but I know next to nothing about server configurations.

Comment: What parameters did you pass to rsync? Did you preserve permissions?

Comment: Have you also synced any hidden `.htaccess` style files?

Comment: @NickCoons, yes, permissions were preserved.

Comment: @arkascha: That's probably exactly what I did. Also, something I know nothing about. I'll investigate.

Comment: Also: Would .DS_Store files mess things up? They got added when I was messing around with OS X FUSE... I clearly have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks, that was exactly it. Okay, now here's the weird part: Wordpress is erasing it's own rewrite rule in .htaccess... I can add the rewrite code manually, but every time I refresh Worpress, it gets re-written. What?